# Как получить имя выполняющейся в данный момент процедуры в пакете?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть ли способ, получить имя выполняющейся в данный момент процедуры в пакете?

```
create or replace package pack1 as
    procedure proc1;
end pack1;
/
create or replace package body pack1 as
    procedure proc1 is
    begin
        /** Какoe мoe имя? */
    end proc1;
end pack1;
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Currently Executing Procedure Name within the Package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50536323/6571020) от участника [@sqlpractice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5255760/sqlpractice)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50536323/6571020

Answer (score 2):

Избегатйте логики: "Как меня зовут?" в самих процедурах, функциях или методах. Трудно представить ситуацию, когда она там нужна. Поместите эту логику в отдельный логгер.

Для этого воспользуйтесь [UTL_CALL_STACK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_CALL_STACK.html#GUID-2BE2AEB4-51DA-48CA-8B55-0AB6827EF612) или [$$PLSQL_UNIT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-E918087C-D5A8-4CEE-841B-5333DE6D4C15). Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create or replace package pack1 as
    procedure proc1;
    procedure proc2;
    procedure logger;
end pack1;
/
create or replace package body pack1 as
    procedure logger is
    begin 
        dbms_output.put_line ('# unit:'||$$plsql_unit||
            ' iam '||utl_call_stack.concatenate_subprogram (
                utl_call_stack.subprogram(1))||
            ' called from '||utl_call_stack.concatenate_subprogram (
                utl_call_stack.subprogram(2)));
    end logger;
    procedure proc1 is begin logger; proc2; end;
    procedure proc2 is begin logger; end;
end pack1;
/
```

Вызов и результат:

```
exec pack1.proc1

# unit:PACK1 iam PACK1.LOGGER called from PACK1.PROC1
# unit:PACK1 iam PACK1.LOGGER called from PACK1.PROC2
```